# Graphics DrawString

Tags: c#, graphics

```
    private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Image img = Image.FromFile("Картинка.jpg");

        picture.Width = img.Width;
        picture.Height = img.Height;
        this.Width = picture.Width + 40;
        this.Height = picture.Height + 75;

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            Font font = new Font("Verdana", 30);
           Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", 16);
           g.DrawString("Счастье - когда прошлое не", font, Brushes.White, 93, 440);
           g.DrawString("напрягает, настоящее не беспокоит, а будущее впечатляет!", font2, Brushes.White, 60, 490);

        }

        picture.Image = img;

        img.Save("result.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Как сделать так чтобы можно было выбирать шрифт и цвет текста и писать в любой точке на картинке, как в фотошопе? fontDialog, colorDialog пробовал но не понял внедрить его в графику. Благодарю заранее спасибо. Если что то не понятно написал, постараюсь подробнее рассказать!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать свойства [`FontDialog.Font`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.font(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`FontDialog.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.color(v=vs.110).aspx). Заведите поля `currentFont` и `currentColor`, инициализируйте их какими-то значениями по умолчанию и заполняйте при необходимости из диалога.

```
private void btnSelectFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fontDialog.ShowColor = true;

    if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
       сurrentFont = fontDialog.Font;
       сurrentColor = fontDialog.Color;
    }
}
```

А дальше используйте их в вашем коде:

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        g.DrawString("...", currentFont, new SolidBrush(currentColor), 93, 440);
        g.DrawString("...", currentFont, new SolidBrush(currentColor), 60, 490);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище выручил))) Я так и хотел сделать, но в ступор встал. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @Sergey_73 не за что.